# Looking for an open API for to get tracking information from an EMB code

Tags: data-request, food

This might be a lost cause, but been searching for a couple of days now.

I'm looking for a way to track an item of food from it's origin to the supermarket. I have the EMB code for an item, e.g. UK 1715 EC

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you reached out to the http://uk.openfoodfacts.org/ folks?

Comment: I had a look at the site but reach out as well, thanks

Comment: Please could you expand the EMB acronym?

Comment: The first word is European, but not sure after that I'm afraid. It appears only OpenFoodFacts uses it. However I have come across this: http://www.food.gov.uk/enforcement/approved-premises-official-controls/sectorrules on the food.gov.uk website. It's a link to a bunch of spreadsheets that contain processing establishments each owning one of these 'EMB' numbers. Which means as long as an item has one of those codes, I can find where it was packaged. Other than that I think it's a bit of a long shot.